# Video4Linux Y12 Pixel Format for use with OpenCV issues

Tags: opencv, pixelformat, video4linux

I have a [AMG88xx infrared camera](http://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/ADI8000/ADI8000C66.pdf) attached to a raspberry PI 4
i am using the linux [video-i2c](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.19.y/drivers/media/i2c/video-i2c.c) driver 
the driver appears to work correctly

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --all
    Driver Info:
        Driver name      : video-i2c
        Card type        : I2C 1-104 Transport Video
        Bus info         : I2C:1-104
        Driver version   : 4.19.102
        Capabilities     : 0x85200001
                Video Capture
                Read/Write
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps      : 0x05200001
                Video Capture
                Read/Write
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
    Priority: 2
    Video input : 0 (Camera: ok)
    Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 8/8
        Pixel Format      : 'Y12 ' (12-bit Greyscale)
        Field             : None
        Bytes per Line    : 16
        Size Image        : 128
        Colorspace        : Raw
        Transfer Function : Default (maps to None)
        YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
        Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
        Flags             :
    Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
        Capabilities     : timeperframe
        Frames per second: 10.000 (10/1)
        Read buffers     : 1
```

However the output pixel format (Y12) appears to be unsupported by openCV

```
>>> import cv2
>>> capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't open camera by index 0
```

Do I need to build OpenCV with additional support? or somehow convert the pixelformat?

Comment: Could you run your camera using any app like *cheese*? If yes what do u see on the screen?

Comment: im not running with a desktop however i can get output from the camera to the hdmi output framebuffer via ffmpeg `ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pixel_format gray12 -video_size "8x8" -i /dev/video0 -vf histeq,scale=200:200 -f fbdev -pix_fmt bgra /dev/fb0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was related to missing pixel format in OpenCV (see Issue [#16620](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16620)) fixed by [#16626](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/16626)

found by compareing [video4linux pixelformats](https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/v4l/pixfmt.html) with those supported by openCV in [modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need **OpenCV** and `cv2.VideoCapture()` to read that camera. It is just a relatively slow I2C device that you can read directly or using the Adafruit library as in [this example.](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-amg8833-8x8-thermal-camera-sensor/raspberry-pi-thermal-camera)

By all means, you *could* read it as above and then convert from 12-bit to an 8-bit or 16-bit Numpy array and then process with **OpenCV** afterwards, but it is not necessary.

Alternatively, you could embed a subprocess call to `ffmpeg` like I did in the second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60266466/2836621).

Comment: Specifically you need lines like line 7, 34 and 79 of the linked code. I don't have that specific camera to test with so I can't be much more helpful than that

Comment: ive already had that working, it isn't really an answer to the question i asked

Comment: It might have been an idea to mention that! What is your objection to that solution?

Comment: I have added another option.