# ffmpeg piped to python and displayed with cv2.imshow slides rightward and changes colors

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Code:

```py
import cv2
import time
import subprocess
import numpy as np

w,h = 1920, 1080
fps = 15

def ffmpegGrab():
    """Generator to read frames from ffmpeg subprocess"""
    cmd = f'.\\Resources\\ffmpeg.exe -f gdigrab -framerate {fps} -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size {w}x{h} -i desktop -pix_fmt bgr24 -vcodec rawvideo -an -sn -f image2pipe -' 

    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    while True:
        raw_frame = proc.stdout.read(w*h*3)
        frame = np.fromstring(raw_frame, np.uint8)
        frame = frame.reshape((h, w, 3))
        yield frame

# Get frame generator
gen = ffmpegGrab()

# Get start time
start = time.time()

# Read video frames from ffmpeg in loop
nFrames = 0
while True:
    # Read next frame from ffmpeg
    frame = next(gen)
    nFrames += 1

    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (w // 4, h // 4))

    cv2.imshow('screenshot', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break

    fps = nFrames/(time.time()-start)
    print(f'FPS: {fps}')


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code does display the desktop capture however the color format seems to switch and the video scrolls rightward as if it is repeated. Am I going about this in the correct way?

Comment: I eould use `np.frombuffer()` rather than `np.fromstring()` and I would avoid `shell=True` where possible.

Comment: I've tried both of those suggestions with no change.

Comment: Try saving the frames as PNGs immediately after `frame = next(gen)` using `cv2.imwrite(f'frame-{nFrames}.png', frame)` and inspecting the PNGs.

Comment: This is for a realtime application - wouldn't saving this to a file cause delay? I'm aiming for 30-60fps. I'm also looking for why this issue occurs as it seems there was only one other post related to this where the suggestion was to open a pipe as binary which I already tried.

Comment: The point of saving a PNG is to debug/check to find the problem. We can speed it up later. I think the code originates from mine... https://stackoverflow.com/a/60266466/2836621

Comment: Images show the same deal, video comes up as corrupted file/fileextension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause for the problem is: `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.

- The argument `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` redirects `stderr` to `stdout`.
- `stdout` is used as a PIPE for reading the output video from FFmpeg sub-process.
- FFmpeg writes some text to `stderr` and the text is "mixed" with the raw video (due to the redirection). The "mixing" causes weird slides and colors changes.

Replace `proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)` with:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

---

Minor corrections:

As Mark Setchell commended, use `np.frombuffer()` instead of `np.fromstring()` and avoid `shell=True`.

Replace `-f image2pipe` with `-f rawvideo`.
The output format is raw video and not an image (the code is working with `image2pipe`, but `rawvideo` is more correct).

---

Complete updated code:

```
import cv2
import time
import subprocess
import numpy as np

w,h = 1920, 1080
fps = 15

def ffmpegGrab():
    """Generator to read frames from ffmpeg subprocess"""
    # Use "-f rawvideo" instead of "-f image2pipe" (command is working with image2pipe, but rawvideo is the correct format).
    cmd = f'.\\Resources\\ffmpeg.exe -f gdigrab -framerate {fps} -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size {w}x{h} -i desktop -pix_fmt bgr24 -vcodec rawvideo -an -sn -f rawvideo -'

    #proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)

    # Don't use stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, and don't use shell=True
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

    while True:
        raw_frame = proc.stdout.read(w*h*3)
        frame = np.frombuffer(raw_frame, np.uint8)  # Use frombuffer instead of fromarray
        frame = frame.reshape((h, w, 3))
        yield frame

# Get frame generator
gen = ffmpegGrab()

# Get start time
start = time.time()

# Read video frames from ffmpeg in loop
nFrames = 0
while True:
    # Read next frame from ffmpeg
    frame = next(gen)
    nFrames += 1

    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (w // 4, h // 4))

    cv2.imshow('screenshot', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break

    fps = nFrames/(time.time()-start)
    print(f'FPS: {fps}')


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```